# How to understand whether I need to put . sign or @ sign at the end of label in DNS SOA rname record?

Tags: dns

Is there any convention I missed while parsing SOA record RNAME field?

For example amazon.com SOA rname is: root@amazon.com

But when program parses it there is no `@` symbol, it is treated like regular domain label.

Question is how would  I understand whether I need to put `.` sign or `@` sign at the end of label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example amazon.com SOA rname is: root@amazon.com

No it is not:

```
$ dig SOA amazon.com +noall +ans
amazon.com.     14m50s IN SOA dns-external-master.amazon.com. root.amazon.com. (
                2010155050 ; serial
                180        ; refresh (3 minutes)
                60         ; retry (1 minute)
                3024000    ; expire (5 weeks)
                60         ; minimum (1 minute)
                )
```

The `MNAME` ("The  of the name server that was the
original or primary source of data for this zone.") is `dns-external-master.amazon.com.` and the `RNAME` ("A  which specifies the mailbox of the
person responsible for this zone.
") is `root.example.com` (in quotes, definition from RFC 1035 which is canonical on this).

There can never be `@` in the `RNAME` (and even less so in the `MNAME` which should correspond to an hostname). This is because `@` has a special meaning in DNS, and it predates the global use of email as we know today.

You have the example in RFC 1035 explaining things:

```
@   IN  SOA     VENERA      Action\.domains (
                                 20     ; SERIAL
                                 7200   ; REFRESH
                                 600    ; RETRY
                                 3600000; EXPIRE
                                 60)    ; MINIMUM

[..]

Note the use of the \ character in the SOA RR to specify the responsible
person mailbox "Action.domains@E.ISI.EDU".
```

It is further explained in §3.3 of RFC 1034:

```
For mailboxes, the mapping is slightly more complex.  The usual mail
address <local-part>@<mail-domain> is mapped into a domain name by
converting <local-part> into a single label (regardles of dots it
contains), converting <mail-domain> into a domain name using the usual
text format for domain names (dots denote label breaks), and
concatenating the two to form a single domain name.  Thus the mailbox
HOSTMASTER@SRI-NIC.ARPA is represented as a domain name by
HOSTMASTER.SRI-NIC.ARPA.
```

Note that if you do anything around DNS, and specifically any kind of client or server, you MUST absolutely read RFC 1034 and 1035 and **multiple times**. Yes they are full of holes/ambiguities and things that have changed later.
But they must be gospel to your ears otherwise you will have a lot of DNS problems.

After that, as a modern resource, RFC 8499 should be your bible as it has everything related to DNS terminilogy and pointer to resources.

Comment: thanks, got it. What I was looking for was in RFC-1035 8. Mailboxes. `The DNS encodes the <local-part> as a single label.` So it comes as a single label and after that we put `@` instead of `.`

Comment: Yes a single label, hence per normal DNS encoding rules if it happens that this label has a dot, then it has to be escaped as `\.` because `.` is a character with special meaning in DNS.